Getting "The system cannot find the file specified" while converting midi to mp3 using mido and pydub

import mido
from pydub import AudioSegment

def midi_to_mp3(midi_path, mp3_path):
    # Load MIDI file
    midi = mido.MidiFile(midi_path)

    # Create an empty list to store notes
    notes = []


    for track in midi.tracks:
        # Iterate through MIDI messages in track
        for msg in track:
            # Check if message is a note on event
            if msg.type == 'note_on':
                # Add note (pitch, velocity, time) to notes list
                notes.append((msg.note, msg.velocity, msg.time))


    tempo = 120
    duration = 1000

 
    segments = []

   
    for note in notes:
        pitch, velocity, time = note
        # Calculate duration of note based on tempo and time
        note_duration = int(duration * (mido.tick2second(time, midi.ticks_per_beat, tempo) * 1000))
        # Create audio segment for note
        segment = AudioSegment.silent(duration=note_duration)
        segments.append(segment)

    
    audio = sum(segments)

   
    audio.export(mp3_path, format="mp3")


midi_to_mp3("melody.mid", "output.mp3")


This is the full error message:

C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\env\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2023.1.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 56448 --file C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\musicrypt.py 
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9161.41)
C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\env\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\env\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1496, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\musicrypt.py", line 70, in <module>
    convert_to_mp3('melody.mid', 'audio.mp3')
  File "C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\musicrypt.py", line 46, in convert_to_mp3
    midi_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(midi_path, format="midi")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\env\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Dipika\Study\musicrypt\env\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 585, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(app_name, patch_arg_str_win(cmd_line), *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1


I am trying to convert text to melody using music21 library which unfortunately gives mid file format as output. I am not able to play this mid file through any web broswer. That's why I tried to convert the mid file using mido and pydub libraries. But each time I run this my system gives an error "The system cannot find the file specified". I have my melody.mid file in the same path as the python file.
I was expecting to get a mp3 file in the end

When you run the python script, are you in its directory as your current working directory?  When the script is run and it looks for "melody.mid", it is looking relative to your current working directory, not the location of the python script.

@nigh_anxiety yes I am in the current working directory. I have tried giving the full path also. But still getting the same error. Looks like it has something to do with the libraries I am using. Still debugging!!

Could you post the full error message and traceback into the question?

ffmpeg and ffprobe are part of a software suite that is ordinary software for your computer, not a Python library. That's why you see Popen in the stack trace - the Pydub library is trying to run this program as a separate program and capture its output. It must be installed separately. Please see the linked duplicate for details. Incidentally, the problem described here has nothing to do with mido.

You are getting this error because you have not installed the additional non-python dependencies for the pydub library. pydub relies on additional programs being installed on  your system to handle the encoding/decoding of various audio file formats.  As stated in the package installation instructions:

Installing pydub is easy, but don't forget to install ffmpeg/avlib (the next section in this doc)

From the Depenendencies section of the same documentation:

You can open and save WAV files with pure python. For opening and saving non-wav files – like mp3 – you'll need ffmpeg or libav.

There is an additional set of directions specifically for setting up ffmpeg, if needed.  ffmpeg is the default library that pydub tries to use if it can't determine what library is installed.
